# Second Order Series Solution $- C(n), C(n+1), C(n+2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working through some Second Order Differential Equations using the Series solution.

sorry about the poor math formatting. $C(n+1) \to$ the $(n+1)$ is a sub

$$y'' - 2xy' + y = 0$$

So I begin with:
\begin{align}
    y   &= \text{series } (0,\infty) \text{ of } c(n)x^n
\\
    y'  &= \text{series } (1,\infty) \text{ of } n\cdot c(n)x^{n-1}
\\
    y'' &= \text{series } (2,\infty) \text{ of } (n-1)\cdot n\cdot c(n)x^{n-2}
\end{align}
then:
\begin{align}
    xy' &= -\text{series } (1,\infty) \text{ of } 2nC(n)x^n
\\
    y'' &= \text{series } (0,\infty) \text{ of } (n+2)(n+1)C(n+2)x^n
\end{align}
The solution then adds $y + xy' + y''$. What does $xy'$ start at $1$ while the two other equations start at $0$? Is this legal, and if so, why?

I'm working out of the James Stewart 7th edition. Ch17 Section4 Example 2

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to see another solution worked out that may be slightly different than your book?

Comment: Sure, I'm still a little confused on the logic and how to complete these problems. I would appreciate any help. I don't as much care about this specific problem as much as learning these problems in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed legal, but in order to finish solving your problem, you must change the indices so that they match. Thereby you get the recurrence relation that the $c_n$'s must satisfy, and thus together with initial value conditions you can usually solve your problem explicitly.